# Using the Meetup GraphQL API on a command line

Tags: oauth, command-line-interface, meetup

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Meetup GraphQL API on a command-line app. Part of the problem is that I need to register an OAuth client using https://www.meetup.com/api/oauth/create/. That page doesn't allow me to register the URLs I've tried. I tried a `http://localhost` but that didn't work. I tried the URL to my meetup, also, no luck.

Then I created a Github repo, but the web page didn't like that URL, either.

[image: Field that requires URL]

Tips?